# bootstrap handling a ajax form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get this form to load for a couple days now, but all I can get is the form to submit to a page (not what I want, I want the form to submit and then close the modal and then put a success message from news.php into the div "thanks" holder).

Can anyone spot the issue I am having where it will one load the "news.php" page?

```
<div id="thanks"></div>    
<div class="modal fade" id="newsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="newsModalLabel">Add a News Post</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="addNew" role="form" method="POST" action="news.php">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter title here...">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="7" placeholder="Enter news post here..."></textarea>
                                  </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addNews">Add News Post</button>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and the javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button#addNews").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "news.php",
                    data: $('form.addNew').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
                        $("#newsModal").modal('hide');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
  </script>
```

Comment: What is the result? Do you have a blank page in your dialog after submission?

Comment: No it will load the news.php file and pass the data. Nothing in the div I want to poulate.

Comment: Remove the action attribute from the form tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't pass the event object to your click binding :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) { // pass the event object
    $("button#addNews").click(function(){
        e.preventDefault(); // disable the POST of the form by the submit button
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "news.php",
            data: $('form.addNew').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
                $("#newsModal").modal('hide');
            },
                error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Oops, I forgot [the BootPly of my test](http://www.bootply.com/124780).
I just replaced your POST request to a GET one, I don't know how to make POST request inside BootPly.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean but I am still getting to same problem. Thank you though. It has to be something I am overlooking.

Comment: Thanks I got it working now! I was calling the javascript in the wrong spot, BEFORE my jQuery framework. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

button#addNews is the submit button for the form, also it's click event is binded with an ajax call. When it is clicked, ajax process begins to execute while the form is being submitted.

You need to remove `<form...` start & end tags.

Comment: Or include a call to `event.preventDefault()` after the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to now do nothing, I changed the form to <div

Comment: Just realized you are sending data by serializing the form. You cannot remove form tag in this case. Please use Kryten's method

Comment: It still is not doing what I would like. http://aj2controls.com/skirrpets/admin/ is the link to it if you have time to take a look.